# Query for multiple SQLite tables with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, query-string

Forgive me if my question sounds stupid as I'm a begginer with SQLite, but I'm looking for the simplest SQLite query PHP solution that will give me full text results from at least three separate SQLite databases.

Google seems to give me links to articles without examples and I have to start from somewhere.

I have three databases:

- domains.db (url_table, title_table, date_added_table)
- extras.db (same tables as the first db)
- admin.db (url_table, admin_notes_table)

Now I need a PHP query script that will execute a query and give me results from `domains.db` but if there are matches also from `extras.db` and `admin.db`.

I'm trying to just grasp the basics of it and looking for a starting point where I can at least study and learn the first code.

Comment: You can do it one after the another (query the first, test the data than query the others if needed). What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Kmeixner: Aren't the SQLite databases in a different file? You can't JOIN multiple databases in SQLite, because You need to connect to the other the db files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you connect to '`domains.db`', query what you need, save however you want, than if there were a result in the first query, you connect to the others and query them.

```
$db1 = new SQLite3('domains.db');

$results1 = $db1->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');

if ($results1->numColumns() && $results1->columnType(0) != SQLITE3_NULL) {
    // have rows
    // so, again, $result2 = $db2->query('query');
    // ....
} else {
    // zero rows
}

// You can work with the data like this
//while ($row = $results1->fetchArray()) {
//    var_dump($row);
//}
```

Source:

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php

Edit.: A better approach would be to use PDO, you can find a lot of tutorials and help to use it.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydatabase.db');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM MyTable');
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo 'Example content: ' . $row['column1'];
}
```

You can also check the row count:

```
$row_count = sqlite_num_rows($result);
```

Source: http://blog.digitalneurosurgeon.com/?p=947

Comment: thank you for answer. I will play with the code and return if more question. My main concern is that if I can query multiple dbs at once but I see that ONE can query as many as possible , just use same code for every database after another on the same page, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Your databases are in different files, so you need to connect to each of them. So, basically yes, you do the same three times.